# Cannot login as a regular user on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, users, password, passwd

This user is a unpriviledged SFTP access user on our server, it was used during the stay-home order earlier this year due to Covid19, and I'm using it today to prepare some work for use tomorrow.

Since I forgot its previous password, I reset it using the command `sudo passwd <user>`, and I wasn't able to login, I explicitly unlocked it using `pw unlock` and checked `/etc/master.passwd`, and confirmed I successfully changed the recorded password hash. Yet, I wasn't able to login using either `sftp` command remotely, or with `login` command during the admin ssh session.

What could possibly be the cause of this?

**Update**

I copied password hash from another unpriviledged user to it and it still cannot login, that other unpriviledged user can login however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skimming through man page for `passwd(5)`, I found the `pwd_mkdb(8)` command. Running:

> `pwd_mkdb -p /etc/master.passwd`

solved the problem.

In essence, the problem is that, `/etc/master.passwd` file didn't get updated into `/etc/pwd.db` and `/etc/spwd.db`. These 2 are "cached" database files in Berkeley database format (present for the presumed purpose of speeding up credential lookup).

`pwd_mkdb(8)` is the system management command for generating "password database", which is the table of user information. I updated the server to 12.2-RELEASE last month, and forgetting to run the command is probably the cause.

Comment: Changing the password for a user using `passwd` should have updated these databases automatically.  It is unclear why this did not happen.